# Automation Microsoft Azure AD login in Robot Framework (4.1.1)

Tags: oauth-2.0, outlook, azure-active-directory, automated-tests, robotframework

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsE9J.png)

I am trying to sign in with AD Microsoft Login, and it is asking for an OTP from Register Mobile.

How do I verify OTP from my own mobile to sign in with Microsoft in the robot framework?

```
Authorize OAuth 2.0    ${AUTH_URL}    ${CLIENT_ID}    ${REDIRECT_URI}
...                     response_type=code    scope=your_scope
...                     state=your_state    login_hint=your_login_hint
...                     display=your_display    prompt=your_prompt

${code}=    Get OAuth Authorization Code

Fetch OAuth Tokens    ${TOKEN_URL}    authorization_code=${code}
...                     grant_type=authorization_code
...                     client_id=${CLIENT_ID}    client_secret=${CLIENT_SECRET}
...                     redirect_uri=${REDIRECT_URI}

${access_token}=    Get OAuth Access Token
```